# View is using height of contained UIImageView, how do I get it to resize?

Tags: ios, swift, stack, uistackview

I have the following layout:

[image]

There are no height constraints on any of the views. `Background Image View` is pinned to the top, bottom and leading edges of the container. All the vertical compression and hugging priorities are left as default.

I am having the issue that the `Container`'s height is determined by the height of the image. I want it to ignore the height of the image and use the height determined by the stack views and labels. How can I achieve this?

I have tried changing the compression resistance policy to the lowest value on the image view and this didn't make any difference.

Comment: Height of labels inside stack views are fixed? Also can you please show the desired design as well?

Comment: Repost your layout image with all of the constraints visible (all of the > arrows expanded).

Answer (score 0):

One of the following solutions can solve your problem.

1. If they are vertically aligned, you can add "equal height" constraint from container to stackView.
2. If they are horizontally aligned, you can add "top" and "bottom" constraints from container to stackView.

Comment: equal height will cause the container view to use the image views height

Comment: Please keep current constraints of imageview. Additionally, try to set equal height imageview to stackView

Answer (score 0):

top, left, right, bottom of imageView and stackView both equals to container. Then change the content hugging priority and content compression resistance priority as:

For more information about these values: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-content-hugging-and-content-compression-resistance-priorities-476fb5828ef

[image]